# Display the Data types of a given list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

i want to print the Data types of a list all at once. I have a mixed Data types in a list, like integers, strings and Alphanumeric values. I am able to get it individually but i am not able to get it all at once.

Comment: Show the attempts that you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use **list comprehension** feature of python like

```
list1 = [1,'f', 1.1, 1.01]
print([type(i) for i in list1])
```

result will be like `[<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]`

Comment: thanks alot..!! and may i know what topic cover this?

Comment: @RushendraRushi [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) feature in python

Comment: yeah i saw that, can you help me to print data and datatype side by side at the same time?

Comment: what you mean by side by side?

Comment: thanks, i found the answer for my problem. I am sorry that i didn't ask the question properly

Answer (score 2):

If you have python list say `l`;

```
l = [1,'f', 1.1, 1.01]
print([type(i) for i in l])
```

will give;

```
[<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
```